# mysql alternative string literal for ? to supply the text of the prepared statement

Tags: mysql

Example inside stored procedure that working good:

```
SET @first_condition = input_parameter_1;
SET @second_condition = input_parameter_2;

SET @vs_query = "
    SELECT my_column FROM my_table WHERE one_column = ? AND other_column = ? LIMIT 1;
";

PREPARE stmt FROM @vs_query;
EXECUTE stmt USING @first_condition, @second_condition;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**The question:**

Is there in mysql another alternative to use some more descriptive like *:my_var* instead the *"?"* simbol, or something similar like as used in PDO?

I am loking for some like this:

```
SELECT my_column FROM my_table 
WHERE one_column = :first_condition AND other_column = :second_condition LIMIT 1;
```

instead:

```
SELECT my_column FROM my_table 
WHERE one_column = ? AND other_column = ? LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, doesn't look like [per documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html) Though you can consider to concatanate the variable values directly while preparing

Comment: About concatenation .. this I knew but then there is risk of injection?